# In matplotlib, why is loglog plot different from log10(x) log10(y) plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

I think I am a little confused on loglog plots. I plotted a loglog plot and compared to a regular plot  after taking log10(x) and log10(y). The shape is the same as expected but the axis is different and I don't understand why. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
def Q_Function(x):
  return 0.5 - 0.5*special.erf(x/np.sqrt(2))

def Pe_BPSK(gamma):
  return Q_Function(np.sqrt(2*gamma))

gamma = np.arange(1, 35, 1)
p_bpsk = Pe_BPSK(gamma);

plt.loglog(gamma, p_bpsk)
plt.show()

plt.plot(np.log10(gamma), np.log10(p_bpsk))
plt.show()
```

[image: Link to Graphs]

Comment: Of course axes are different, you are plotting different values - to be precise the log of them, so the new axes correspond to the old exponents.

Comment: `loglog` sets the scales of the plot. it doesn't change the values

Comment: I think I am having a major dumb moment. So if I wanted to create a loglog plot without using loglog function I wouldn't just take the log of x and y and plot?

Comment: Yes you would, but 10^{-11} would plot to -11, 10^{-5} would plot to -5.